# ClearInterval в другой функции

Tags: setinterval, javascript

Как с помощью функции **bot_stop**, остановить binterval?

```
function bot_start() { // старт
 var binterval = setInterval(function() {
  if(...) {
   clearInterval(binterval);
  }
 }, 1000);
}

function bot_stop() { // стоп
 clearInterval(binterval); // так не работает
}
```

Comment: вынесите var во внешний scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Объявление var binterval является локальным, поэтому за пределами функции оно не видно. Надо соответственно менять функции так, что бы оно было видно в другой. Либо убирать var и делать binterval глобальной:

```
function bot_start() { // старт
 binterval = setInterval(function() {
  if(...) {
   clearInterval(binterval);
  }
 }, 1000);
}
```

Либо использовать другие возможности, так например, по моему будет лучше, что бы не засорять глобальную область:

```
function bot_start() { 
 var binterval = setInterval(function() {
  if(...) {
   clearInterval(binterval);
  }
 }, 1000);
 return binterval;
}

function bot_stop() { 
 clearInterval(bot_stop.interval); 
}

//так должен выглядеть вызов bot_start
bot_stop.interval = bot_start();
```

Comment: :) есть и более простые способы ограничить область видимости:

    (function() {
        var my="test";
    })()

Comment: Есть много способов решения и у каждого из них свои достоинства и недостатки. Замыкания хорошая вещь, но как его эффективно применить в данном случае, я не вижу. В общем-то и мои примеры не идеальны тоже, если посидеть и подольше подумать над задачей))

Comment: так просто всё обернуть в замыкание, вот вам и локальные переменные действительные для обоих функций :) http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/YU6qN/

Comment: Зациклился на тем, мало ли там может быть форма и вызов организован через <button onclick="bot_stop()"> стоп </button> которому я перекрою доступ или еще что. Но в общем согласен, код JS надо отделять от HTML и данный вариант с замыканием лучше.